# Which of the boolean operators is more optimised?

Tags: javascript, node.js, optimization

I'm using JavaScript using the Node.js framework.

I have the following if statement.

```js
if (this.LRR && this.LRR._DataStore === Key) return this.LRR;
```

And I have:

```js
if ((this.LRR || {})._DataStore === Key) return this.LRR;
```

Assume that `this.LRR` is an object, but by default `null`. Which one is more optimised?

Comment: Have you actually raced the horses? https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Comment: Is this a serious question?  Why would it possibly matter?  If you have a legit reason to know, then it will likely be dependent upon the particular JS interpreter and you will just have to test the two options in the interpreter you care about.  But, there's a 99.999% chance this is premature-optimization or an attempt to optimize something other than one of your top 100 most important things to spend time optimizing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of JavaScript's [Short-circuit evaluation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Description) the execution stops whenever it encounters `&&` after `false`.

So in your case 1st one is more optimized and efficient

```js
if (this.LRR && this.LRR._DataStore === Key) return this.LRR;
              ^
              |
Execution stops right at here
```

While in the second case, whole condition is executed

```js
if ((this.LRR || {})._DataStore === Key) return this.LRR;
// => if (({})._DataStore === Key) return this.LRR;
// => if (undefined === Key) return this.LRR;
                           ^
                           |
Execution stops right at here
```

Answer (score 1):

I dont have node.js but this might help you

```
optimalisationTest();

function optimalisationTest() {
    let startTime = Date.now();
    console.log(startTime);

    //Test with maybe even 1000000 to check what is faster.
    for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        //Test this first. After remove this line below and change it to the other if statement u have. Check what is faster.
        if (this.LRR && this.LRR._DataStore === Key) return this.LRR;
    }

    let endTime = Date.now();
    console.log(endTime);

    //End time - begin time to check how long it took to execute the code.
    console.log(endTime - startTime);
}
```

I am not sure if your if statement works more then once, but please let me know the result.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
if (this.LRR && this.LRR._DataStore === Key) return this.LRR;
```

has a short circuit and avoids to take a new object **and** then takes a property for checking against a value.

If possible, you could take the [optional chaining operator `?.`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining).

```
if (this.LRR?._DataStore === Key) return this.LRR;
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but the OP asked a performance question, not how else to do it.

Comment: I never knew this was a thing, but I'm not surprised. This isn't supported by the Node framework, unfortunately.